# How to mark a menu item checked using mfc in vc++ 6?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, mdi

I created a menu Styles with an item U for underlining with a code:

```
void CPersonalEditorView::OnStylesU(){
    CHARFORMAT cf; 
    cf.cbSize = sizeof(cf);
    cf.dwMask = CFM_UNDERLINE;
    cf.dwEffects   = CFE_UNDERLINE;
    GetRichEditCtrl().SetSelectionCharFormat(cf);}
```

I want to mark a check when the "U" menu item is clicked.
I have tried:

```
CMenu *pMenu = GetMenu();
if (pMenu != NULL)
{   
    pMenu->CheckMenuItem(ID_STYLES_U, MF_CHECKED | MF_BYCOMMAND);
}
```

not worked
and:

```
CWnd* pParent = GetParent();
CMenu* pMenu  = pParent->GetMenu();
pMenu->CheckMenuItem(ID_STYLES_U, MF_CHECKED);
```

not worked and :

```
CMenu popupMenu;
popupMenu.LoadMenu(IDR_PERSONTYPE);
popupMenu.CheckMenuItem(ID_STYLES_U,MF_CHECKED);
```

not worked.
Tell me anything that could help me.

Comment: Please read the documentation on On_UPDATE-COMMAND_UI handler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display your menu in the resource editor and right-click and select **Add Event Handler**:

[image: Menu]

Next, you need to select the [UPDATE_COMMAND_UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8c866kb.aspx) message and choose the appropriate class. Then click **Add and Edit**:

[image: Wizard]

Then, you just update the menu item as needed. For example:

```
void CMainFrame::OnUpdateOptionsLanguageItalian(CCmdUI* pCmdUI) 
{
    pCmdUI->SetCheck( theApp.GetProgramLanguage() == LANGUAGE_ITALIAN ? 1 : 0 );
}
```

In the above example I am using [SetCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/ccmdui-class#setcheck). There are other choices aswell if you look at the class.

If your menu was inside a `CDialog` then you can't use the above mechanism, because the architecture is not there by default. You could add a lot of the framework but it is not worth it. For a dialog object you create a method and manually call it on demand. In your method you would do:

```
CMenu *pMenu = GetMenu();

if (pMenu != nullptr)
{
    pMenu->CheckMenuItem(ID_VIEW_ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY,
        (m_pAssignHistoryDlg != nullptr)
        ? MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_CHECKED : MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_UNCHECKED);
}
```

So now you know both approaches, dependant on the context of your menu.

That said, in your question you don't provide much context about your menu. Is it a popup menu? Is it part of the mainframe? When are you invoking the menu?

Hopefully the above, as indicated in the comment to your question, will suffice.